# Setting PATH environmental variables permanently Centos Web Panel Install... Works from SSH, not Webpage

Tags: linux, path

My zip function isn't working when being called from a php script, but works straight from the SSH prompt.

code in the PHP file that returns nothing `var_dump( exec('zip -r domains.zip "domains"') );`

code in the php file which works as expected `var_dump( exec('/usr/bin/zip -r domains.zip "domains"') );`

I've added the path to /etc/profile, I've added it to my ~/.bashrc but can't get the web user to be able to use it.

I'm new to this and it's a VPS so I'm not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that permissions are adequate on the files being accessed - you want to ensure that the user accessing them is able to execute them.

Comment: That was my first thought! I asked the host that, but they didn't respond. I'll see what I can do on my own about that.

Comment: The user running the php scripts has the permissions needed.